# Questions on polynomial ring in several variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

1. Let $K$ be an infinite field. Prove that different polynomials in $R=K[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$ don't lead to the same function $K^n \to K, x \mapsto f(x)$. (solved)
2. Find $I \subset R$ and different elements in $R/I$ that take the same values on $Z(I)$.

Comment: It may help to pay close attention to the word *infinite.*  Can you come up with a counterexample in the case of a finite field, namely a pair of distinct polynomials that define identical functions?

Comment: For this to happen, it would have to happen in the univariate case.  There are already Questions here on proving it does not happen in one variable over an infinite field.

Comment: Not really sammy black

Comment: The Case $n=1$ in Qn 1 follows from the fact that a polynomial of degree $k$ has at most $k$ roots. You have to find a way of using induction on $n$ to do the general case.

Comment: I think I got it for $R[X]$.
 Let $f, g \in R[X], f \not= g $, with degree at most  $n$. THen $f-g$ also has dregree at most $n$ , and thus it has at most $n+1$ zeros. $K$ is infinite and this  $K$ has elements that aren't zeros of $f-g$.  Say $a$ is such an element, then $f(a)-g(a) \not=0$. And thus $f(a) \not= g(a)$. And Thus $f \not=g$. \\

Comment: I think I also got the induction proof. But I cant find the ideal!!